# windows 8 contact picker issue

Tags: windows-8

I have queried the People app contacts in windows phone through PickMultipleContactsAsync method. it retrieves the selected contact informations. But inthat i am unable to get most of the fields like  the Company name, Job Title, Fax, Website etc fields. Only Name, Emails, Phone number, Address fields were available.